# How to get Regular Customer list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to get list of regular customer records. can anybody help me in the mysql query to get regular customer records.

Regular customer records defination : A customer who place single order in month for last 3 month that called regular customer.

ie.: customer A place one order on jun, jul and aug that called regular but if he place order on may, jul and aug then it's not a regular customer.

Following my table list:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_mst` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipAddress` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_mst` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `custId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK customer_mst(ID)',
  `grandTotal` float NOT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `custId` (`custId`)
)
```

Comment: are you looking for customers who placed an order in the **last** three months, or in **any** three consecutive months? The questions implies the former, but the example applies the latter.

Comment: Also, can a customer place several orders in the same month?

Comment: @Mureinik 
1) consecutive of last three months
2) customer place any no of order in single month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way, but not the fastest:

```
select * from customer_mst
where ID in (
    select custId from order_mst
    where createdDate <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) and createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
)
and ID in (
    select custId from order_mst
    where createdDate <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
)
and ID in (
    select custId from order_mst
    where createdDate <= NOW() and createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)
```

Hint: try using InnoDB engine and [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) instead of comments.

Comment: In your query, there is no checking for consecutive orders for 3 months

Comment: If you want the total count of orders made by the client just add this condition: count(order_mst.ID) >= 2
Alternatively you can sort by the number of orders placed: order by count(order_mst.ID)
But beware that using COUNT() is not a good practice. You should instead keep that count in separate column.

Comment: That is not correct solution cause count will be more than 3 for single month also and it's not consecutive

Comment: Ok, did not get that at first look at your question. In order to do that you must take all three months into separate conditions, and act accordingly. I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: @MaciejSz i think that following changes would make query more perfect do you agreed? 

select * from customer_mst
where ID in (
 select custId from order_mst
 where month(createdDate) <= month(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) and month(createdDate) > month(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
)
and ID in (
 select custId from order_mst
 where month(createdDate) <= month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and month(createdDate) > month(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
)
and ID in (
 select custId from order_mst
 where month(createdDate) <= month(NOW()) and month(createdDate) > month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)

Comment: Ofcourse, if you are looking for discreet month values. I'm just wondering if it is susceptible to edge-case errors (i.e. produce same month by two different conditions).

Comment: I'd advice that you calculate the month values outside of the SQL query - in your business logic. That way you could write unit tests, and be certain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select customer_mst.*,DATEDIFF(now()-order_mst.createdDate) as diff_days 
from customer_mst
left join order_mst on (order_mst.custId = customer_mst.ID)
group by customer_mst.ID having diff_days  < 90
```

Comment: In your query, there is no checking for consecutive orders for 3 months

Comment: Yes your Right @  Upendra Chaudhari i missed that part sorry.

Comment: it will give me record of customer who place order before 3 month but i want customer record who place order in each month for last 3 month check my ie. : customer "A" place one order on jun, jul and aug that called regular but if he place order on may, jul and aug then it's not a regular customer.

In above case customer "A" have to place an order on each month (jun, jul and aug) to become an regular customer.

Answer (score 0):

not efficient though

```
$month1=mysqli_query(select * from customer_mst
where ID in (
    select custId from order_mst
    where createdDate <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) and createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
));
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($month1);
if($rows>0){
$month2=mysqli_query(select * from customer_mst
where ID in (
    select custId from order_mst
    where createdDate <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
));
$rows1=mysqli_num_rows($month2);
if($rows1>0){
$month3=mysqli_query(select * from customer_mst
where ID in (
    select custId from order_mst
    where createdDate <= NOW() and createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
));
$rows2=mysqli_num_rows($month3);
if($month3>0){
echo 'regular customer';}
};
};
```